# Soap bubble with air blown in and charge distributed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, fluid-dynamics, bubbles

[image: The question]

So,  I was trying to do this question and here is my attempt:

I first tried work out the surface tension forces like so:

I did $ F= PA$

$ P = 4 \frac{\gamma}{r}$ by laplace law

so,

$ F = 16\gamma \pi r $

But this answer is wrong, And I'm even more confused how to account for the unknown charge thing

However I attempted that by writing the self energy as a function of radius and then taking it's derivative, as so,

$$ F_{e-stat} = \frac{-Q^2}{ 4\pi \epsilon r^3}$$

But, adding this to the original thing leads me no closer to the answer...

The actual answer:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{ \pi m}{12 \sigma}} $$

Where exactly did I go wrong in my logic? can I not do $ F = P \cdot A$ ?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.